# While debugging, debugger skips intermediate return statement and/or executes both branches of an if statement, etc

Tags: c#

Using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.4.5

When stepping through the code below, after hitting and continueing from the line 'return exists', the debugger will not jump to the end of the function, but instead step to the line 'return true' after which the function will return true, regardless of the value of 'exists'. Ofcourse, it should not execute the line 'return true' in the first place...

```
 List<files> filesWithTheSameHash = GetFilesByMD5Hash(md5Hash);
            if (filesWithTheSameHash.Count == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (contents != null)
            {
                Boolean exists = filesWithTheSameHash.Where(f => f.contents == contents).Any();
                return exists;
            }
            
            return true;
```

What I tried was to run the code in both Visual Studio, as well as JetBrains Rider and there is no difference in behaviour.

I checked whether the project was compiling as a release build. It is not. It is a debug build. The configuration is to "Active (Debug)".

I checked whether compiler optimizations were enabled. For this, I went to the 'Build' tab of the project's properties and found 'Optimize code' to be unchecked.

I updated visual studio. No change.

I stepped through one other function in the same class and it also displayed similar behaviour.

I enabled 'Suppress JIT optimization on module load'. No change.

--- UPDATE 1 ---

There is an error in the code.

f.contents == contents

needs to be:

f.contents.SequenceEqual(contents)

--- UPDATE 2 ---

I wrote "regardless of the value of 'exists'." That is incorrect, what is returned is the value of the boolean 'exists', eventhough the debugger hits 'return false'. At this point the question has changed. The code is working fine, but how can I stop the debugger from hitting two return-statements in the same function (which is confusing) ?

Comment: Are you sure your code is running on single thread?

Comment: It is not my intention to have it run by multiple threads, so pretty sure it is only running on a single thread; I should have noticed while stepping through the code I think. It is not running on the UI thread however, perhaps that might explain?

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints on all lines of this code and see where and how and why it goes

Comment: Following your suggestion, I noticed that 'exists' was 'false', where I had assumed it was 'true', and falsely concluded that the last 'return false' was executed. It turns out that, eventhough while stepping through the code, the last return will be 'hit', what is actually returned is the boolean 'exists'. And following your suggestion, setting breakpoints on all lines, I saw that when F5-ing through the code, instead of F10-ing, the last line, as one would expect, is not hit.